# Error using custom loss functions in Keras for model training

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am training a VGG-16 model toward a multi-class classification task with Tensorflow 2.4, Keras 2.4.0 versions. The y-true labels are one-hot encoded. I use a couple of custom loss functions, individually, to train the model. First, I used a custom cauchy-schwarz divergence loss function as shown below:

```
from math import sqrt
from math import log
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
from scipy import special

def cs_divergence(p1, p2):    
    """p1 (numpy array): first pdfs, p2 (numpy array): second pdfs, Returns:float: CS divergence"""    
    r = range(0, p1.shape[0])
    p1_kernel = gaussian_kde(p1)
    p2_kernel = gaussian_kde(p2)
    p1_computed = p1_kernel(r)
    p2_computed = p2_kernel(r)
    numerator = sum(p1_computed * p2_computed)
    denominator = sqrt(sum(p1_computed ** 2) * sum(p2_computed**2))
    return -log(numerator/denominator)
```

Then, I used a negative log likelihood custom loss function as shown below:

```
def nll(y_true, y_pred):
    loss = -special.xlogy(y_true, y_pred) - special.xlogy(1-y_true, 1-y_pred)
    return loss
```

And compiled the models as below during training the models individually with these losses:

```
sgd = SGD(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)  
model_vgg16.compile(optimizer=sgd,
              loss=[cs_divergence], 
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

and

```
sgd = SGD(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)  
model_vgg16.compile(optimizer=sgd,
              loss=[nll], 
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I got the following errors when training the model with these loss function:
With cs_divergence, I got the following error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

With nll custom loss, I got the following error:

```
NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (IteratorGetNext:1) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported
```

I downgraded the Numpy version to 1.19.5 as discussed in [NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (2nd_target:0) to a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58479556/notimplementederror-cannot-convert-a-symbolic-tensor-2nd-target0-to-a-numpy) but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

try maybe:

```
loss=cs_divergence
means without the Brackets.
```