# How to solve, Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (IteratorGetNext:1) to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have passed a custom loss function to the Keras model, where I am trying to inverse_transform my labels before calculating the rmse score.

I have transformed my labels of shape (n,1) by standard scaler, where n represents the number of records in label.

##### My code

```py
# standardization
lab_scaler2 = StandardScaler().fit(label2)
scaled_lab2 = lab_scaler2.transform(label2)

# custom loss function
from keras import backend as k
def root_mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
    try:
        y_true = lab_scaler2.inverse_transform(y_true)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'y_true: {e}')
    try:
        y_pred = lab_scaler2.inverse_transform(y_pred.reshape(-1,1))
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'y_pred: {e}')
    return k.sqrt(k.mean(k.square(y_pred - y_true)))
```

##### Error I am getting

but it is giving an error, which I have recorded in a log file. The error is as follows

```
# log file
ERROR:root:y_true: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (IteratorGetNext:1) to a numpy array. 
This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported
ERROR:root:y_pred: 
        'Tensor' object has no attribute 'reshape'.
        If you are looking for numpy-related methods, please run the following:
        from tensorflow.python.ops.numpy_ops import np_config
        np_config.enable_numpy_behavior()
```

I found some [related problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58479556/notimplementederror-cannot-convert-a-symbolic-tensor-2nd-target0-to-a-numpy) but it doesn't work for me

Comment: have you tried to do the inverse trasformation in a lambda layer?

Comment: lambda layer means?

Comment: "This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported" This is very explicit, you cannot use non-keras backed functions inside a loss, you cannot use numpy functions inside a loss.

Comment: Then how should I descale my labels inside the function using Keras, any code @Dr.Snoopy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by snoopy, you can't call numpy function in a loss function, even converting to a numpy array wont work, for all the problems involving gradient.

But in your case what you are trying to call is just a Standard Scaler, this method just does:

`z = (x - u) / s`

where u is the mean of the training, and s is the standard deviation of the training.

standard scaler is a linear trasformation, just do it by hand, you just need to compute the mean and the variance of the data, instead of calling the scaler just do a multiplication and an addition (the inverse operation of the scaler), find mean and variance and do the inverse by hand, its a one line expression:

`z = (x - u) / s` -> `(z * s) + u = x`.

just take the tensor, multiply it for the variance and sum the mean.