# How to iterate over a tensor of unknown size in the call method of a custom layer

Tags: python, numpy, keras, tensorflow2.0

The following code contains a runtime error.
Trying to keep things not too complicated here's what my custom layer looks like -

```
class MyCustomLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        .
        .
        .

    def build(self, input_shape):
        .
        .
        .

    def call(self, input_tensor):
        .
        .
        .
        output = []
        for elem_index in range(int(tf.size(input_tensor))):
            output.append(
                self.transform_element(elem_index, input_tensor, other_stuff)
            )

        output = tf.reshape(output,input_tensor.shape)
        return output

    def transform_element(self, elem_index, input_tensor, other_stuff) -> int:
        # Returns an integer value
        # This function accesses input_tensor based on elem_index
        .
        .
        .
```

This code basically attempts to create an input_tensor sized tensor `output` with each element transformed based on its location.

The problem with this code (as far as I debugged) is that `input_tensor.shape = (None, int, int, int)`
So tensorflow places a Temporary Tensor when `tf.size(input_tensorflow)` is called.
So the elem_index is a Placeholder Tensor instead of an integer value.
The transform_element function accesses some elements from input_tensor based on elem_index and computes another integer that it returns.
The error occurs when transform_element attempts to calculate this integer. It uses a complicated algorithm (numpy operations and other objects) all assuming that it is transforming an integer, not a tensor (or placeholder).

I was getting the following error initially -
`NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor to a numpy array.`

I updated tensorflow based on [NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (2nd_target:0) to a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58479556/notimplementederror-cannot-convert-a-symbolic-tensor-2nd-target0-to-a-numpy)

Now I get ValueError inside transform_element at a place where I'm trying to compare two integers.
The code that computes the new integer is definitely correct (exhaustively tested for integers). I don't know what else to do. Been stuck for more than 3 days on this. Thank you for reading this.

Also is there any better way to do this?

Comment: I don't know how easy you can do it, but I would personnally try to rewrite the function in tensorflow instead of numpy.
Also, it is better to try and not loop through the batches, tensorflow is meant to process batches in parallel.